# Reference in Excel VBA code does not work the first time program is started

Tags: excel, vba

I do some coding of Excel AddIns (using Excel 2016), which have to be used by another user (using Excel 365), too.

In order to manipulate XML, I added the reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0; everything works perfectly fine on my machine.

Running the code on the other user's machine shows that the reference is not checked (although the underyling dll is available at the expected file location).

I added some code to programmatically add the reference (no error handling yet):

```
Sub AddXmlReference()    
    Dim ref As Reference
    Dim existRef As Boolean
    existRef = False

    For Each ref In Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References
        If ref.Name = "MSXML2" Then
            existRef = True
        End If
    Next ref

    If existRef = False Then
        Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msxml6.dll"
    End If
End Sub
```

Starting the program on the other user's machine shows some behaviour I do not understand (and I could not find anything helpful):
The first time the program is executed, it runs into an error (user defined error at the module that tries to manipulate XML); thereafter, the program works nicely. If I close excel and restart, the same behaviour starts again. Summarizing, it looks like:

- Excel does not store the reference (which in a way is understandable, as the underlying code dercertain reasons is is opened read-only; in a way however it is not, as the underlying code does have the reference)
- Whilst running the code, the added reference cannot be used
- Within one excel session, the reference is stored

Is there a way to make this added reference being stored permanently? Or did I miss something out?

Comment: Until recently the default installation of Office 365 was 32 bit.  What version does your user have, 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: Have you trusted access to the VBA Project Object Model from **Macro Settings**?

Comment: Actually the references are added to a specific *file* not to Excel, so if you save that file after the reference was added the reference should be stored permanently. So if your file is an add-in you need to save that add-in. • Alternatively use [LateBinding instead of EarlyBinding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation) to avoid that references need to be added at all.

Comment: @Freeflow: All versions are 32 bit versions

Comment: @foxfire: yes, trusted access is granted, as well as the reference to extensibilities

Comment: PEH  says it and I think it's important to know what Early and Late Binding mean and to understand the differences..

Comment: @PEH: That is the strange thing I do not understand: The file (the .xlam file) has the reference stored, but when opened on this other machine, it seems to have been lost

Comment: @alexander Try to use Late Binding, then you don't need to care about the references at all.

Comment: @PEH: I am not too familiar with early and late binding; how could I use code from a dll referenced to without referencing it? and would that mean that I have to re-write the whole code?

Comment: It sounds to me like the user has a different version of the add-in. If it was saved with the reference set, it would either be available, or ticked but with `'MISSING:'` at the start of the name.

Comment: @alexander Read [Early Binding v/s Late Binding in Excel VBA Programming](http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2018/09/vba-referencing-and-early-binding-vs-late-binding/). And yes, you need to change some code but it's some variable declarations/initializations only.

Comment: @rory: no, that is not the case: the box is just not ticked, it does definitely not say "MISSING: " (I know that sometimes, especially when switching between versions, a reference can be set to MISSING). And the code used is one and the same code from a network location.

Comment: Like @Pᴇʜ said, late binding should resolve your issue. There are pro's and con's to both late and early bindings. You just have to understand what they are and when to use them

Comment: Thank you all, I will check the early binding link, and see if I can figure out how to resolve (and update this question, obviously)

Comment: References are workbook-specific as has been said. It is not possible for the same workbook to have different references set.

Comment: @ all, thank you for your support. It seems I trapped into a completely different issue related to an internal network problem; behaviour is OK now again. I tried to look into the early vs late binding options, but found it to be too complicated for the moment and do not want to change (especially as everything works fine again). Please advise if I should set this question to "answered"

Comment: @alexander you cannot set it to answered because there is no answer just comments ;)